# App Crash while fetching Contact list due to large data

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to fetch all the phone numbers and names of contact list. It's forking fine with small number of contact list But app crashes while fetching large number of contacts.
Here Is my code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

int position=0;
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
            String phone=null;
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }

            SearchGetterSetter searchContactList=new SearchGetterSetter();
            searchContactList.setPosition(position);
            searchContactList.setFist_name(name);
            searchContactList.setContactNo(phone);
            searchContactList.setChecked(false);
            contactList.add(searchContactList);
            originalList.add(searchContactList);
            position++;
        }
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

Is there any way to fetch contact list in batches?

Comment: could you attach the error log

Comment: Right now i don't have error log. But when i fetch 10 contacts . the same code on same device( which produce crash )is working fine.

Comment: Put a try catch inside the while loop and print the error  it may be Integer parse error you may have phone number with + symbol this may cause error

Answer (score 0):

Large processed like this should not be done on the UI Thread..do this inside 
a Java's Thread. Or the better option is using AsyncTask in android API.

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<(inputParams),(returnTypeForProgressUpdate), (retunType)> {
 protected Long doInBackground(inputParams... inputparam) {
     int input = inputparam[0];
     // Your Code In Here
     return modifiedInput;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // for update bar 
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
  //this is in the ui thread so use the result   
  showDialog("Loaded");
 }
```

For better info visit.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)

Comment: Thanks @BSathvik. I'm using the same. i fetched contact list in Async Task. Is there any way to fetch contact list in batches?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know